# Why is my form submission still refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and know some basic jQuery. However, when testing out a simple test ajax script, I'm running into difficulty.

And I have read other questions that our similar to mine but I haven't been able to get any results.

What I hope to achieve: when the input field is "onblur"ed it submits the form it's in, sends the ajax request to a file that simple echos what was submitted in json format and returns it and logs the response to the console.

Here is what I have done. This is the form that submits when you click off the input field:

```
<form id="title_form" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project_title">Project Title</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <input onblur="return document.getElementById('title_form').submit();" id="project_title" type="text" class="form-control" name="project_title" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var root = $('#url_root').val();
  var php_file = 'assets/ajax/update.php';
  var url = root+php_file;
    $('#title_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response)
            {
              var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
              console.log(jsonData);
           }
       });
     });
});
```

And this is the update.php page that echos the post data in json format:

```
<?php
    
    if(isset($_POST['project_title'])){
        echo json_encode($_POST['project_title']);
    }
?>
```

The onblur submit form part is working fine!

However, my ajax script isn't preventing the page being refreshed (despite the e.preventDefault) and it's not logging the response in the console (my guess is because the ajax script isn't working at all because I have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you call the `submit` event on the native form Element, not a jQuery object referencing the form. As such the jQuery `submit` event handler does not fire.

To fix this problem, and improve your code, remove the outdated `onclick` attribute from the HTML and use an unobtrusive event handler for the `blur` event - although note that `change` seems more appropriate as it fires on blur, but only after the value of the field has been changed, which will save you some needless server requests. Then you can trigger `submit` on the jQuery object holding the form reference, like this:

```html
<form id="title_form" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="project_title">Project Title</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <input id="project_title" type="text" class="form-control" name="project_title" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $('#title_form');

  var root = $('#url_root').val();
  var php_file = 'assets/ajax/update.php';
  var url = root + php_file;

  $('#project_title').on('change', function() {
    $form.trigger('submit');
  });

  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(jsonData);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I adjusted my code: but got this in my console:

script.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: Plus this at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:16)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (script.js:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: You're using jQuery slim which doesn't have AJAX methods (amongst others). You need to replace that with the full version of jQuery

Comment: yep that did it ! you sir are brilliant! Thank you for your help, some people can be really harsh on this platform but this was brilliant and I have actually learned from your answer !

Comment: @MikeAbineri Your question was detailed, researched and with code so we would normally treat you much better than "gimme teh codez" type questions